# Es posible bajar de manera masiva datos sobre las facturas desde el SAT sin usar un API externo?

Tags: api

Necesito bajar datos de facturas (CFDI) recibidas desde el SAT pero no encuentro la opción de hacerlo directamente del SAT ys olo veo APIs externos como el de Belvo. No quiero bajar el XML uno por uno y descargar la metadata del SAT no me sirve porque no tiene toda la información de las facturas y de los productos comprados. Cómo le puedo hacer para hacerlo directamente del SAT?

Ya traté hacerlo con Belvo y sirve muy bien pero me gustaría hacerlo directamente con el SAT

Comment: El SAT tiene un [Servicio de descarga masiva de CFDI](https://www.google.com/search?q=SAT+descarga+masiva+CFDI).

Comment: Pero hay manera de descargar solo los datos de las facturas en lugar de bajar las facturas en si? Por ejemplo en formato JSON?